# How to Identify the GUID that WinUSB is using to identify the USB Device

Tags: c#, winusb

I have some code which is already written, where we are using WinUSB Library (MadWizard.WinUSBNet) to identify the USB device and program the same (USB Plug and play to wirelessly interact with another device).

The code is something like this.

```
USBDevice usb= MadWizard.WinUSBNet.USBDevice.GetSingleDevice("51630179-b622-4834-8ff7-9916b1446884");
```

I was trying to figure out what this GUID value is mean for. I have gone through the device manager ->device properties and checked hardware Id, compatible Id etc.. But could not match this GUID anywhere.
I have referred this [article to understand more](https://www.techspot.com/community/topics/plug-and-play-overview-how-windows-finds-drivers-for-usb-devices.127886/).
Please help to identify the property which the GUID which is referring to.

Comment: I could find the GUID under the following registry key. BUt I am not sure about the significance of this registry value and how to add it in other machines.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\DeviceClasses\{51630179-b622-4834-8ff7-9916b1446884}

Comment: please *[edit]* your question to add more information, rather than commenting in direct reply to yourself.